# Application of multilist data structure in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am reading about multilist data structure in Algorithsm in C++ by RobertSedwick.

> If a multidimensional matrix is sparse, then we might use a multilist
>   rather than a multidimensional array to represent it. We could use one
>   node for each value in the matrix and one link for each dimension,
>   with the link pointing to next item in that dimension. This
>   arrangement reduces the storage required from the product of the
>   maximum indices in the dimenstions to be proportional to the number of
>   nonzero entries but increases the time required for many algorithms

Kindly request your help in understanding above statement with simple example.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: I think it just says that you can implement it as a "jagged array", where you have a list that contains each row of the matrix, and each row is a list. The downside of this is the fact that you'll have to seek a(x,y) by traversing the relevant lists, rather than having instant access.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example implementation:

```
class MultiList
{
    public:
        int value, x, y;
        MultiList *next_x, *next_y;
        void add( int xcor, int ycor, int val );
}
```

The MultiList Class has pointers to the next object in the same row, and the next object in the same column. For a 2 dimensional MultiList, you would need the following dummy nodes:

```
root -> col0 -> col1
  |
  V
row0
  |
  V
row1
```

With `row0.next_x` pointing to `null`, `col0.next_y` pointing to `null`, etc.

To insert the value '3' at `(0, 1)`, you start at `root`, and keep going `next_x` until you reach the the `1` column dummy node `col1`. Then starting at that node, keep looking at its children until either

`this->next_y == null` or `this->next_y.y > ycor`

```
root -> col0 -> col1
  |               |
  V               V
row0              3
  |
  V
row1
```

Then you insert a new node with your values into that list. You repeat with the corresponding row node in x instead of y.

```
root -> col0 -> col1
  |               |
  V               V
row0      ->      3
  |
  V
row1
```

---

**Analysis**: This implementation is good for really sparse multidimensional arrays, considering you only allocate memory per node you need to add, which means memory complexity is O(n). Insert/delete is O(n), as you potentially have to walk through every existing node if they are all in the same row or column. Lookup is also O(n) for a similar reason.

Comment: Wouldn't access be `O(n^2)`, as you may potentially traverse `n` dummy nodes and then `n` real nodes to reach `(n, n)`?